# Convert MS Access memo to a link field to an exported txt file

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to convert MS Access column with memos into a column with links to external files with exported content of a memo?

I have asked Google and did not find any hints. I do not shy from using VBA in Excel but I have no idea where to start with  Access. I guess a code converting the table would have to go record by record, exporting each memo to a txt file, naming this file and creating a link in a new "links" field. 
Can you help me find a solution? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: There's no magic way to do this, you're going to have to do it yourself but your proposed approach seems right to me. Good luck!